# Apache Server - Content-Type HTTP Header

Tags: apache, http-headers, mime-types

Hi I am having an issue where the client side is unable to `connect/play` video content from a `.mp4` asset file located on an Apache Server.

I am suspecting the issue has to do with the `Content-Type` parameter in the HTTP Headers.

How can I modify this `Content-Type` parameter to see if this is the issue?

I'd like to try `video/mp4`, `audio/mp4`, `audio/m4a`, `audio/aac`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix this issue on Apache you need to add the following content to the ‘.htaccess‘ file which is found in your document root (public_html or htdocs).

just paste this to your .htaccess (required mime types)

```
AddType video/mp4 mp4 m4v
AddType audio/mp4 m4a
```

You can also add these mime types directly in the Apache configuration file ‘mime.types’

```
/etc/httpd/conf/mime.types
```

add required mime.types.

```
  video/mp4 mp4 m4v
  audio/mp4 m4a
```

then restart apache.

Comment: I used the Chrome plugin "HTTP Headers" and it showed "video/mp4".

Comment: Any idea why it's not making an effect?